# What sort of drivers are used to connect Node.js applications to a database?

Tags: node.js, database

***If this question is inappropriate for stackoverflow please feel free to remove this question.***

Typically when we connect to relational databases from applications (e.g. Java or .Net), a JDBC or ODBC driver is used.

What driver does a Node.js application use to connect to databases? It appears that there isn't a standard way (similar to JDBC or ODBC).

I observed that each vendor provides a driver for Node.js.

Here are a couple that I searched for MS SQLServer and Oracle.

1. [Node.js Driver for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt652093.aspx)
2. [Oracle Database driver for Node.js](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/scripting-languages/node_js/index.html)

There are other node.js libraries, some that uses ODBC under the covers.Is there a standard around this space (similar to JDBC for Java)?

Though this question is specifically for RBDMS, it is applicable to NoSQL databases too.

*Note:* *I primarily use Java/JEE (and its ecosystem) for my solutions.*

Comment: Please only tag with JDBC if the question is actually about JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard Database access API for Node.js. However if you like the JDBC APIs you can use a JDBC driver in your Node application with Avatar.js. This works fine with Oracle's UCP and JDBC thin driver (and maybe other drivers). This technique requires a thread pool to turn the blocking JDBC calls into non-blocking calls. At 2016's JavaOne, new asynchronous Database APIs for Java were presented which will hopefully be part of JDK10 and when that happens these APIs will fit quite nicely from within Node.js.